# C#'s HttpClient ReadAsStreamAsync

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have an issue downloading a 400MB+ file using C#'s HttpClient ReadAsStreamAsync - the issue is that only around 213864187 bytes are being read out of 427724800 and then

```
read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token)
```

keeps returning 0 for no obvious reason.

Anyone had similar problem?

```
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
    var totalRead = 0L;
    var buffer = new byte[4096];                            
    var moreToRead = true;

    const int CHUNK_SIZE = 4096;
    var fileStream = File.Create(filename, CHUNK_SIZE);                            
    int bytesRead;
        do {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token);

        if (read == 0) {
            moreToRead = false;
            this.Percentage = 100;
            if (fileStream != null) {
                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                }
        } else {
            var data = new byte[read];
            buffer.ToList().CopyTo(0, data, 0, read);
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {                                       
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }                                    
            // Update the percentage of file downloaded
            totalRead += read;

            if (canReportProgress) {
                var downloadPercentage = ((totalRead * 1d) / (total * 1d)) * 100;
                var value = Convert.ToInt32(downloadPercentage);
                this.Percentage = value;
                this.BytesReceived = totalRead;
            }
        }
    }
    while (moreToRead);                           
}
```

Comment: What status are you getting from the 1st response?  If you are in chunk mode (http1.1) after each chunk is received you must sent the next chunk message.  I've never been able to successfully get http 1.1 to work with Net Library.  I always get a timeout error due to not sending the next chunk message and the server disconnects the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's something strange going on around this bit:

```
buffer.ToList().CopyTo(0, data, 0, read);
bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
if (bytesRead > 0) {                                       
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

I'd expect you to write the bytes you just read into the `fileStream` - i.e. `fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)` on its own. However you copy the buffer to a `data` array (which is never used again), then read from the stream *again* into `buffer` (this time synchronously), and write *that*.

So you're throwing away half of the downloaded bytes. No wonder "only around 213864187 bytes are being read out of 427724800"!

Also, use a `using` block for your `fileStream`, rather than using an explicit `.Dispose()` call. Also, if you're copying one array to another, use `Array.Copy` rather than `array.ToList().CopyTo(...)`.

Comment: Good Catch, though here copying to another `byte[] (data)`, is just a wasteful exercise, main loss happens due to this double reading operation, `bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);` and why mixing Async and Sync, it shall always be Async operation for IO